# How is it possible that I can treat a pointer to a linked list as if it's the linked list itself in this piece of code?

Tags: c

Could anyone care to explain why this piece of code written below works?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int main(void)
{
    node *first = NULL;
    node *second = NULL;
    node *third = NULL;

    first = malloc(sizeof(node));
    second = malloc(sizeof(node));
    third = malloc(sizeof(node));

    first->number =1;
    first->next = second;

    second->number =2;
    second->next = third;

    third->number = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", first->number, second->number, third->number);

    return 0;
}
```

From my understanding, when I allocate memory to a node *, I am technically allowing that node pointer to point to an array of nodes. Therefore, node * would be a different data type compared to a single node, and number and next would be components that are exclusive to a single node. However, first->number and first->next can both be assigned values, which confuses me, because that means first, which was initialized as a node * can now be accessed as if it is a single node.

Comment: Every node on a list is the start of a list.

Comment: Every node is an element and a pointer to another node. Don't think of it as "every node points to an array". Every node may point to a node, which may point to a node, which may point to a node, which may point to a node...

Comment: It may help to remember that `first->number` is just a convenient alias of `(*first).number`.  You really are accessing the `number` member of a single node, namely `*first`, the one which `first` points to.  If you must think of `first` as pointing to an array, it's an array of size 1, and as usual in C a pointer to an array actually points to its first element.  So this is also equivalent to `first[0].number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From my understanding, when I allocate memory to a node *

You allocate a memory area with enough space to store a `node`.

> I am technically allowing that node pointer to point to an array of nodes. Therefore, node * would be a different data type compared to a single node, and number and next would be components that are exclusive to a single node.

`first = malloc(sizeof(node));`

`first` is a pointer to the memory area which has been given by `malloc`. There is nothing related to any `array` here. `first` will refer to a node, which will be different from `second` node and different from `third` node.

```
    first->number =1;
    first->next = second;

    second->number =2;
    second->next = third;

    third->number = 3;
    third->next = NULL;

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", first->number, second->number, third->number);
```

This code is pretty simple, he create 3 different nodes, set their values `number` and print them.

If you want a continuous memory area, you can write:
`array = malloc(3*sizeof(node));`

In this case, the memory area will be continious. You could use the syntax `array[0]` to refer the `first` node, `array[1]` to refer to the `second` node and `array[2]` to refer to the `third` node.

Answer (score 1):

> From my understanding, when I allocate memory to a node *, I am technically allowing that node pointer to point to an array of nodes. Therefore, node * would be a different data type compared to a single node, and number and next would be components that are exclusive to a single node.

Untrue. It may be easier to distinguish between a linked list and an array when we look at time complexity of various operations.

In an array, elements are adjacent to each other and occupy one contiguous block of memory. Therefore, if you want to access some element, all you need is simple arithmetic on pointers and you can immediately "jump" to the right location.

Linked lists, on the other hand, require you to step through each element, because it's not until you've stepped into one that you'll know where the next one lies in memory. To get to the nth element of a linked list, you need to iterate through `n-1` prior elements.

---

Consider the following code, which can be used to find the last element in a linked list:

```c
node *last;
for (last = first; last && last->next; last = last->next);
printf("Address of the last node: %p\n", last);
```

It actually **doesn't matter which node you pass** as the initial value of `last`, because all nodes are linked up in such a way that you will always arrive at the same result. The only difference is how many nodes you'll have to jump through before you get there.

---

Perhaps your confusion stems from the fact that struct node's `next` member's type is a pointer to another node, and sometimes we use pointers to describe an array. That is not the case here, the pointer only represents a single element.